# JQuery Dialog open() killing text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, highlighting

Is it possible maintain text selection on the screen while a Dialog box opens still?

I don't want the dialog to interfere with any selections the user may have made on the page.

**What happens is** if I select a certain range of text and activate the dialog box, the event firing that opens the dialog seems to deselect the previously selected text.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You said it yourself. Any click will deselect the text.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, I think you're misunderstanding.

No one is clicking anything, the firing of the dialog box is causing the text to be deselected.